# How to check internet available to mobile packdata or not..?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios6, reachability

Our app support offline and online

So every step we need to check internet available to network or not.

When we using [**Reachability**](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) class then wi-fi off/on check it properly.

And in another we are also use [**SimplePing**](https://github.com/chrishulbert/SimplePingHelper/blob/master/PingTester/SimplePingHelper.m) it is also work properly with Wi-fi using ping to host.

We are also check ICMP socket programing for this but it is only support to wi-fi.

But when we are using mobile packetdata how can we check internet is available to mobile or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSURL *scriptUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.co.in/"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:scriptUrl]; 
if (data)
    NSLog(@"Device is connected to the internet"); 
else 
    NSLog(@"Device is not connected to the internet");
```

Comment: We have also use this code but when internet is not available to network then it take more time for response and in app many times we required response in less than 2 Seconds... so we can not use this code...

Answer (score 0):

This is something that a `OS` detects itself or by the `ISP`. You can check whether the internet is available through `WiFi`, or through `CellularData` or some other medium.

Internet access will automatically disconnected if user has consumed the data.

You can not check this by writing code.